# Insert an item into unordered array

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to insert a number into an unordered array, but it has some logical errors. used code is,

```
    int NoOfItems = 5 ;
    int MyArray[] = {1,6,3,9,5};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
    int m_Number = input.nextInt(); 
    if (NoOfItems < MyArray.length) {
        MyArray[NoOfItems] = m_Number;
        NoOfItems = NoOfItems + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyArray));
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Would be better if you would include what errors you got and how you tried to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MyArray array is of length 5, so it can hold objects in indexes 0-4. You are trying to insert an object in index 5 which will give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Please note that Arrays in Java have immutable size.

You need to create a new array of size 6 and copy the old array's content into it and then add 5th index. Or else, you can use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are fixed size. Their size cannot be modified after creation. If you want dynamic length arrays, consider using java.util.ArrayList

Your example in [online java IDE](https://kasadara.com/p/71d0c8fa-db7c-444e-aeb4-f3d65bfcedca)

Answer (score 0):

Size of arrays are fixed in java, best thing you can do is to use ArrayList.

But if you want to implement this with arrays, here how it works:

```
int myArray[] = {1, 6, 3, 9, 5};
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
int mNumber = input.nextInt();

// Allocate new array
int newArray[] = new int[myArray.length + 1];
// Copy contents
System.arraycopy(myArray, 0, newArray, 0, myArray.length);
// Put a new number into last cell in array
newArray[newArray.length - 1] = mNumber;

myArray = newArray;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question :

> it has some logical errors

the code inside the if condition never executes as

> "NoOfItems" is 5 and "MyArray.length" returns 4.
>
> condition is 5<4

which never becomes true therefore you never add an element into the array. If you correct your condition and try to add an element into the array you would get a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

And like the rest of the answers state if your want a re-sizable array in java go for arrayList. Array's are of fixed length in java.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has a fix value when you created it. You can just change the values in and cannot add news.

You should do that :

```
ArrayList<Integer> MyArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //create a new list
    MyArray.add(1); // put 1 at index 0.
    MyArray.add(6); // put 6 at index 1.
    MyArray.add(3); // ...
    MyArray.add(9); // ...
    MyArray.add(5); // ...
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
    int m_Number = input.nextInt(); 
    MyArray.add(m_Number); //put the entered number at the end of MyArray

    System.out.println(MyArray);
```

Tadaa !